# Issues with building a VRT. from OS map tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, image-pyramids, vrt

I am trying to speed up rendering of OS raster map tiles in QGIS.

The tiles are 1:10k Tiffs - about 130 of them.

When I attempt to build the VRT it says complete, then it shows up an error message:

**Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support rotated geo transforms.**

The only settings I had on whilst creating the VRT were: resolution - highest 
                                                         Add to canvas after finishing

As you can see from the image some of the tiles were successful. I didn't have a problem with creating a VRT for 1:50k or 1:250k map tiles.

Any suggestions or advice on speeding up rendering of OS map tiles (such as pyramids) would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do your tiffs have tfw files with rotation values in them?

Comment: We always converted tiffs to png - purely for small files and faster displays. Setting a Layer with Scale visibility <10,0001 also was more efficient.

Comment: This is OS StreetView? Anyway, it might be worth checking that each TIFF has its own world file (in the same directory). N

Comment: +1 for nhopton - For some reason OS likes to bundle its world files into a separate directory to the rasters, if you get a world file at all.  I have had to download them separately on occasion.